# Storing data into json field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with a JSON column. I added this to my model in order to cast it automatically when I want to read it:

```
protected $casts = ['data' => 'array'];
```

If I manually insert this in the database to the json field everything works fine:

```
{"age": "15", "name": "John Doe"}
```

I read the model field and it's returned as an array.

I cant figure out how to store data through my app. I tried using this

```
$model->data = json_encode(['John Doe']);
```

But when I check the database this is what is stored:

```
"{\"name\":\"John Doe\"}"
```

And it's not casted when I want to use it. How can I solve this?

PLUS: Is there some documentation about the json field usage? I coulnd find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I just make $model->data = ['nombre' => 'John'] and it's stored properly

Comment: Are you trying to say it's because you omitted the array key i.e. _'nombre'_ or that you didn't have to use `json_encode`?